# How do we define power of irrational numbers?

Tags: calculus, irrational-numbers

power of rational numbers for me can be defined as multiplying $m$ times the $nth$ root of $x$. because we have:
$$
 x^{\frac{m}{n}} 
$$
when : $m,n \in \Bbb Z $.
Is this definition correct? if no what is the correct one and if yes, how can I extend this definition for irrational numbers? because we can't write them in the form $a/b$.

Comment: This is correct. For irrational numbers $y\in\mathbb{R}_+$, you could find a sequence $\left\{y_n\right\}$ of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ and define $x^y$ as the limit of $x^{y_n}$ when $n\rightarrow +\infty$ (this would require some careful justification: you need to make sure that $x^{y_n}$ is well defined, then prove that the limit exists and does not depend on the choice of $\left\{y_n\right\})$. The standard definition uses the $\exp$ function and defines $x^y=\exp\left(x\ln y\right)$, imposing $y>0$.

Comment: Note:  rationals are dense in reals

Comment: @J. W. Tanner, what does dense mean?

Comment: One way to formulate it is to say that for every two real numbers $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$  such that $x<y$ there is a rational number $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<q<y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $x^q$ is defined for $q \in\mathbb{Q}$. Given real numbers $x>0$, $y>0$ then $$x^y = sup \{x^q,q \in\mathbb{Q}, q<y \}$$ and extend it for $y<0$ for a full definition over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

I actually made a big post about extending exponentiation: see [Generalization of the root of a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733068/generalization-of-the-root-of-a-number/3733083#3733083)

Essentially, just as @charlus said - you define a sequence of rational numbers that converges to the irrational number you are interested in, and take a limit of the principal values. For example, if we had ${\pi}$, and a sequence of rational approximations of it ${\pi_n}$:

$${\pi_1 =\frac{3}{1},\pi_2 = \frac{31}{10}, \pi_3 = \frac{314}{100}...}$$

By construction it converges to ${\pi}$. Now, if we want to compute ${a^{\pi}}$:

$${a^\pi := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{\pi_n}}$$

(note: you take the principal, positive real roots in the limit). You can also do this with any irrational quantity you want!